# Minutes to hh:mm format in SQL Server 2008 query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column `Time` in my table. It holds a time value in minutes, ie: 605. What I want it to show it as 10:05, as `hh:mm` format.

I am doing it like this:

```
...
Time = cast(AVG(Time) / 60 as varchar) + ':' + cast(AVG(Time) % 60 as varchar),
...
```

It shows the value as 10:5, but I want to make it as 10:05 and I couldn't find out a way to add '0' before '5' in the minutes section.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you do the formatting in your presentation layer instead?

Comment: nope, has to be in sql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression to do this.

Also you should always specify the length of varchar when you use `cast`, or it would only show the first character.

```
case when len(cast(AVG(Time)%60 as varchar(2))) < 2 then '0'+cast(AVG(Time)%60 as varchar(2))
else cast(AVG(Time)%60 as varchar(2))
end
```

Comment: It will show the first 30 characters. It will use a default value of 30. Not 1.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  TIME =  CASE WHEN @t < 600 THEN '0' ELSE '' END + 
  CAST(Time / 60 as varchar(10)) + ':' +RIGHT(100 +(Time % 60), 2)
```

Example:

```
DECLARE @t int = 55121

SELECT 
  TIME =  CASE WHEN @t < 600 THEN '0' ELSE '' END + 
          CAST(@t / 60 as varchar(10)) + ':' +RIGHT(100 +(@t % 60), 2)
```

Result:

```
Time
918:41
```

Comment: For some situations I have large minute amounts, like more than 100h, In this case I would need 6 chars. When I try increase char amount it shows me seconds as well, which I dont want. Can you help me to arrange this as well. Like minutes: 6001 -> 100:01

Comment: @EmelUras I am wondering, 6001 would be 404:01 in my book. Is that the result you want ?

Comment: 100hours = 6000minutes , then 6001 minutes = 100:01. Am I wrong?

Comment: Thought you wanted days for that digit

Comment: @EmelUras fixed to return 100:01

Comment: One last question., I checked from http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp but couldnt see. How can I use the format dd:hh:mm
6001 -> 04:04:01 or 
1000 -> 00:16:40
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add a Right('0' + ...,2) expression as below to get the '0' in there.

```
Time = cast(AVG(Time) / 60 as varchar) + ':' + RIGHT('0'+cast(AVG(Time) % 60 as varchar),2)
```

To answer your question in comments, getting DD:HH:MM is a similar setup.

```
DayTime = cast(AVG(Time) / 1440 as varchar) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + cast((AVG(Time) / 60) % 24 as varchar),2) + ':' + RIGHT('0'+cast(AVG(Time) % 60 as varchar),2)
```